# Working with credential provider sample of Windows 7 SDK

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, authentication, credentials, credential-providers

I am developing a custom windows login so that user either can user webcam (face recognition) or username and password. I am able to show a window with all required control at login screen but I don't understand how to authenticate with provided username name and password. Window uses **GetSerialize()** function for this purpose.

```
GetSerialization(
__out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE* pcpgsr,
__out CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION* pcpcs, 
__deref_out_opt PWSTR* ppwszOptionalStatusText, 
__in CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_STATUS_ICON* pcpsiOptionalStatusIcon
)
```

above is function signature. As you can see system uses `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_GET_SERIALIZATION_RESPONSE*` and `CREDENTIAL_PROVIDER_CREDENTIAL_SERIALIZATION*` pointer to get info about username and password. How I can call this for authentication. Or is there any alternative method for doing this at the time of login.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how did you managed to make the credential provider sample to work? I am trying to the same type of application(face recognition login) but i'm stack with the credential provider. I use windows 7 professional and SDK 7.0. I've build the SampleCredentialProvider app from the SDK sample folder, it creates the dll file all the registry things but at login there is no new user (Administrator or Guest like in the document in the sample folder). Is there a trick or did i skip something? Thanks.

Comment: i also had trouble...   but i was compiling for x32 and then trying the code on a x64 machine....  did not work....  recompiled for x64 and it worked.  ymmv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder whether you have solved this by now?

**You** don't call `GetSerialization()`, that's called by Windows (e.g. by WinLogon to perform an interactive logon). You just have to fill the serialization response and the serialized credential. If you pass back a response saying that you have successfully collected a credential from the user then the serialized data is passed to the Local Security Authority for checking.

If you actually want to get the credentials into your own application you can do so using `CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials`.